# how to write sql statement for exporting data based on conditions from database to Excel in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, export-to-excel

I am working on a function "Export data from sql server database to Excel in MVC3", I want to select data based on certain conditions and then export the selected data to excel. Now I have achieved the following function, say, in the screenshot, if I select "Will expire this month" and then submit,  it will only display members who will expire this month in the excel, not all the Members. If I select two dates in the calendar, it only displays members who expires between the two selected dates. Also, I can export data from database to excel based on the sql statement. The problem is I can write sql statement for exporting all the data from database to excel, not based on the conditions (expire this week, expiry this month...). I post my codes. Any ideas? Many thanks.   [image: My function shotscreen]

**RenewalDate Controller**

```
      public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["BreadCrumbs"] = new List<BreadCrumb> { 
            new BreadCrumb { Url = UrlMaker.ToDefault(), Title = "Home" },
            new BreadCrumb {Url = UrlMaker.ToReportsArea(), Title = "Reports Area"},
            new BreadCrumb { Title = "Renewal" } };

        List<string> expiryOptions = new List<string>();
        expiryOptions.Add("Will expire this month");
        expiryOptions.Add("Expire next month");
        expiryOptions.Add("Will expire this week");
        expiryOptions.Add("Expire next week");
        expiryOptions.Add("Have expired");
        ViewBag.ExpiryOptions = new SelectList(expiryOptions);
        ViewBag.a = 0;
        ViewBag.ExpiryDate = string.Empty;
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string option, DateTime? expireFrom, DateTime? expireTo)
    {
        ViewData["BreadCrumbs"] = new List<BreadCrumb> { 
            new BreadCrumb { Url = UrlMaker.ToDefault(), Title = "Home" },
            new BreadCrumb {Url = UrlMaker.ToReportsArea(), Title = "Reports Area"},
            new BreadCrumb { Title = "Renewal" } };

        Session["option"] = option;

        List<string> expiryOptions = new List<string>();
        expiryOptions.Add("will expire this month");
        expiryOptions.Add("expire next month");
        expiryOptions.Add("will expire this week");
        expiryOptions.Add("expire next week");
        expiryOptions.Add("have expired");
        ViewBag.ExpiryOptions = new SelectList(expiryOptions);

        ViewBag.a = 1;


        if (expireFrom != null && expireTo != null)
        {
            ViewBag.ExpiryDate = (memberRepository.renewalDateQuery((DateTime)expireFrom, (DateTime)expireTo));
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.ExpiryDate = memberRepository.RenewalQuery(option);
        }


        return View();
    }



     private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
             ConnectionStrings["ProActiveMembershipDB"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            sda.Dispose();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }



   public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
    {

        //Get the data from database into datatable

        string strQuery = "select MemberType,OrganisationName, Forename, Surname, Email, ExpiryDateofScheme  from Members ";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);

        //Create a dummy GridView
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView GridView1 = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();


       Response.Clear();
       Response.Buffer = true;
       Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
         "attachment;filename=RenewalMemberList.xls");
       Response.Charset = "";
       Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        //Change the Header Row back to white color
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF");

        //Apply style to Individual Cells
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[3].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[4].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[5].Style.Add("background-color", "green");  

        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];

            //Change Color back to white
            row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;


            //Apply text style to each Row
            GridView1.Rows[i].Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");

            //Apply style to Individual Cells of Alternating Row
            if (i % 2 != 0)
            {
                row.Cells[0].Style.Add("background-color", "#AAE92A");
                row.Cells[1].Style.Add("background-color", "#AAE92A");
                row.Cells[2].Style.Add("background-color", "#AAE92A");
                row.Cells[3].Style.Add("background-color", "#AAE92A");
                row.Cells[4].Style.Add("background-color", "#AAE92A");
                row.Cells[5].Style.Add("background-color", "#AAE92A");
            }

        }
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

        //style to format numbers to string
        string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
        Response.Write(style);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

        return View();
    }
}
```

**Index View**

```
 @model IEnumerable<ProActiveMembership.Areas.Members.Models.Member>
 @{
ViewBag.Title = "Report: Renewal Reports";
Layout = Layout = "~/Views/Shared/ProActive.cshtml";;

 }

<h2 class="PageTitle">
<u>Renewal Report</u></h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "RenewalDate", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form" }))
{
<br />
<p>choose from one of the following options:</p>
<p>
    I want to see members that: @Html.DropDownList("option", (SelectList)ViewBag.ExpiryOptions, "choose...", new { id = "ddl" })
</p>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "RenewalDate", FormMethod.Post))
{

// below date1 is expirefrom date and date2 is the expireto date 
<p>
expire between @Html.TextBox("expireFrom", "", new { id = "date1" }) and     @Html.TextBox("expireTo", "", new { id = "date2" })
</p> 
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
<br />
 }    
  <div class="scrollable">
    <table class="RenewalDateReports">
      <tr class="RenewalDateReports"> 
        <th class="RenewalDateReports">
            Name
        </th>
        <th class="RenewalDateReports">
            Expiry Date
        </th>
        <th class="RenewalDateReports">
            Membership with
        </th>
        <th class="RenewalDateReports">
            Grade
        </th>
        <th class="RenewalDateReports">
            Action
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.ExpiryDate)
    { 
        <tr>
            <td class="RenewalDateReports">
                @item.Forename @item.Surname
                @item.OrganisationName
            </td>
            <td class="RenewalDateReports">
                @item.ExpiryDateofScheme.ToShortDateString()
            </td>
            <td class="RenewalDateReports">
                @item.MembershipGrade.Organisation.OrganisationName
            </td>
            <td class="RenewalDateReports">
                @item.MembershipGrade.GradeName
            </td>
            <td class="RenewalDateReports">
               @* @Html.ActionLink("Notify", "###", new { id = item.MemberID })*@

                @Html.ActionLink("Notify", "Communication", "Member", new { Area = "Members" }, null)


            </td>
        </tr>

       @*  @Html.ActionLink("Export to Excel", "ExportToExcel", "RenewalDate")*@

    }
</table>
</div>    

<br />
@Html.ActionLink("Export to Excel", "ExportToExcel", "RenewalDate")
<br />      

   <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ddl").change(function () {
        var form = document.getElementById("form");
        form.submit();
    });


    $(function () {
        $("#date1").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            firstDay: 1,
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "../../assets/images/calendar.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true

        });
    });

    $(function () {
        $("#date2").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            firstDay: 1,
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "../../assets/images/calendar.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true

          });
       });
     });
  </script>
```

**ExportToExcel View**

```
 @{
  ViewBag.Title = "ExportToExcel";
 }

<h2>ExportToExcel</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

What Have u tried till now to export to excel. There are different dll available to interact with Excel "EPPLUS" is one of them . You can find its tutorial on

http://www.jimmycollins.org/blog/?p=547

You can retrieve data using your conditions through stored procedure or query then can bind that data to excel.

Edited Part:- For jquery ajax call

```
       $('#Exportbtn').click(function () {
                       var drpdownval= $("#DROPDOWN").val();//This Is your selected value
                           $.ajax({
                        cache:false,

                        type: "POST",

                        url: "@(Url.Action("ExportProducts", "Order"))",

//Method and controller to which u r going to pass the data
                        data:"drpdownval=" + drpdownval,

                        success: function (data) {
                            //Write your success code here after returning from ajax method
        //If you have returned view you can assign view to some div
                        },
                        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){

                        }  
                    });

                    });
```

Now In You Controller you need to write the method

```
   public ActionResult ExportProducts(string drpdownval)
    {
    //Your Logic goes here

    return View("ViewName","ModelName");
}
```

//Note that this call returns back only to the ajax call .Leave comment if not Understood

Please check all overloads of Html.ActionLink You should assign value to some variable

try this

```
   @Html.ActionLink(
        "Export To Excel",                                                  // linkText
        "ExportToExcel",                                             // actionName
        "Export",                                                   // controllerName
        new {                                                     // routeValues passes to action
            blogPostId = blogPostId, 
            replyblogPostmodel = Model, 

        },
        null                                                      // htmlAttributes
    )
```

Posted this for ur reference use your parameters.

Comment if still having doubt

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried add conditions in the SQL Query **string strQuery = "select MemberType,OrganisationName, Forename, Surname, Email, ExpiryDateofScheme  from Members ";** For example, I use "where" in the query statement and say ExpiryDateofScheme is less than today. But I think there should be a simply way to write the SQL Statement based on the variable I defined in the controller, do you know how to do that?

Comment: You should use ajax jquery call for onchange function of dropdownlist and pass the selected value to the controller action.

Comment: I use javascript to get the values based on conditions. But I have no idea how to use jquery to get the selected data when I click "Export To Excel" link. Can you provide a sample solution or sample link? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the code, it is a bit difficult for me. In the ExportProducts action, I don't know how to write logic. I think (string drpdownval) should be ExpiryOptions in my controller?

Comment: Yes dropdownval is ExpiryOptions which is your parameter for query.

Comment: I don't use ExportPorducts action, I just use Index action in my RenewalDate Controller, then , I change the code to <script type="text/javascript">
$('#Exportbtn').click(function () {var ExpiryOptions = $("#DROPDOWN").val();
$.ajax({cache:false, type: "POST",
 url: "@(Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "RenewalDate"))",
 data:"drpdownval=" + ExpiryOptions,
 success: function (data) {                            
        //I don't know how to write code here;
 },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
     }  
  });

  });

  </script>

Comment: Also, I found a similar question as mine and tried this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453714/filter-excel-output-using-mvc-3 , I change my code to @Html.ActionLink("Export to Excel", "ExportToExcel", new { ViewBag.option, ViewBag.ExpiryOptions, ViewBag.ExpiryDate }). It does not work.

Comment: You should assign value to parameter in html.actionlink